# Support progress bar in Mdi parent form to display child form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am working on an application that has mdi parent child form.

I have 4 forms  in it when i am clicking on second form's button and then loading another third form say user login page, but it's loading very slow.As for username it has to read data from database and display availabe name in  username combobox.

So what i want is that show  progressbar till the list of usernames is extracted..and as progress bar ends the third form is displayed.

Please suggests how I can implement this.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ? Have you searched for it on Google first ?

Comment: A progressbar doesn't make it go faster.  And a dbase engine doesn't provide a progress indication.  So it is completely useless to solve this problem.  Just start a BackgroundWorker with the Load event handler.  And display a small dialog that you close with RunWorkerCompleted.  Use it apologize for the crummy user interface.  You can stop apologizing when you don't have to run queries that take so long.  Look at the way Google quickly presents a million search hits.